# Javascript reference not changing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following

```
        var obj1 = {
            value: "first value"
        };

        var obj2 = {
            value: "second value"
        };

        var  obj3 = obj2;

        function change(obj1, obj2) {
            obj1.value = "asdasd";
            obj2 = "lol";
        }

        change(obj1, obj2);

        console.log("1",obj1.value);//"asdasd"
        console.log("2",obj2.value);//"secondvalue"
```

why only obj1.value is changed ??

Comment: Welcome to JS!!

Answer (score 0):

When you change the parameter obj2 to point to a string, you loose the reference to the object you passed to it.

```
     function change(obj1, obj2) {
        obj1.value = "asdasd";
        // You are only changing the parameter obj2 not a sub property of the object it contained.
        obj2 = "lol";
    }
```